Not able to pass the value in `@uiw/react-codemirror` component to the `useState` hook
A very simple example:
import React from "react";
import CodeMirror from '@uiw/react-codemirror';
import { javascript } from '@codemirror/lang-javascript';

export default function Test() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("console.log('hello world!');");
  const onChange = React.useCallback((val: string) => {
    setValue(val);
    console.log("val:", val);
    console.log("value:", value);
  }, []);
  return <CodeMirror value={value} height="200px" extensions={[javascript({ jsx: true })]} onChange={onChange} />;
}

Where the value state should be set to val in onChange but it never seems to be.
EDIT

I know that it will not update immediately, but even in the next time onChange is called, it's still the default value. So, not the delay's problem.

I know that I can use useEffect but that will not work either, my final goal is to make a request to send the code content to my backend server whenever the user press Ctrl + S


EDIT
I found a workaround, like the following:
const handleSave = React.useCallback((ev: KeyboardEvent) => {
  if ((ev.ctrlKey || ev.metaKey) && ev.key === "s") {
    console.log("Code:", codeText);
    // then send the code to API
  }
}, [ codeText ]);

React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Registering Ctrl + S handler");
  window.addEventListener("keydown", handleSave);

  return () => {
    console.log("Unregistering Ctrl + S handler");
    window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleSave);
  }
}, [ handleSave ]);

This code re-register the Ctrl + S listener every time the codeText is changed.
But I'm still confused about the state, any clue about that is still welcome!

Remove the useCallback hook. There's not really a point in using that in this case, but regardless, you can't access state in a hook once it's been created, unless you add that piece of state to the dependency array. State is likely changing, but you're not able to log it because you're trying to log it inside of the useCallback hook. If you're insistent on using the useCallback hook, either pass the value into the dependency array or use auseRef hook, which you can access anywhere.
import React from "react";
import CodeMirror from '@uiw/react-codemirror';
import { javascript } from '@codemirror/lang-javascript';

export default function Test() {
  const [value, _setValue] = React.useState("console.log('hello world!');");
   const _value = useRef(value) // Either this
   const setValue = (val: string) => { // And this
    _setValue(val)
    value.current = val
}
  const onChange = React.useCallback((val: string) => {
    setValue(val);
    console.log("val:", val);
    console.log("value:", value);
  }, [
    value // Or this
]);
  return <CodeMirror value={value} height="200px" extensions={[javascript({ jsx: true })]} 
onChange={onChange}
// onChange={(val: string) => setValue(val)} Or this
 />;
}

